# looking for a tool to convert db table to c# model

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

i want to take a table on db and create a model from it.

### table

```
TABLE [dbo].[myTable](
[Column1] [int] NULL,
[Column2] [nvarchar](200) NULL)
```

to

```
 class myTable
{
    public int Column1{ get; set;}
    public string Column2{ get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't use ORM like [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

this ORM allow you to map a table from DB into C# class just use the designer in Visual studio

Answer (score 1):

[Hibernate](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/NHibernateForNET) is a standard tool for this. It is open source and widely used.

Answer (score 0):

[Codesmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/generator) does this nicely. You could try the freeware version [here](http://www.codesmithtools.com/freeware) and upgrade if u like it.

hth.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds almost like a Data Access Layer.  Check out LLBLGEN at http://www.llblgen.com/defaultgeneric.aspx and download their free version.  There are other ones out there but I have only used this one.  It is probably more than just what you are looking for but there may be open source versions you can modify.