# Software that generates C# objects from database tables

Tags: c#, .net, sql

Is there a software to generate C# objects from SQL tables?

Comment: Have you looked at Entity Framework?

Comment: The last time I  saw this asked I suggested Codesmith.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897559/looking-for-a-tool-to-convert-db-table-to-c-model/5897600#5897600

Comment: The question is broad. There are lots of ORM frameworks available now, try adding more details: where it will be used, what additional functionality is required, how large is the application etc.

Comment: The various frameworks are all valid, but you need to identify more details about exactly what you need ot get the right one for you.

Answer (score 4):

Most popular from the Microsoft:

- [Linq to Sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx)
- [Entity
  Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Or [subsonic](http://www.subsonicproject.com/)

Answer (score 1):

See a [list of available frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#.NET). I would add that NHibernate have generated lots of good community feedback.

Also take a look at [Castle Active Record.](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm the creator of [SqlSharpener](https://github.com/aeslinger0/sqlsharpener) which is a light-weight tool that will parse your *.sql files (like in an SSDT project) and create DTO objects and stored procedure wrappers. It is faster than any ORM out there because it generates code via T4 templates to output pure ADO.NET code at design-time, so it's crazy fast.